# How to remove space between grid rows in extjs grid with template column?

Tags: css, extjs, css-grid

What is the right selector to change space between two rows in the extjs grid with template column?

When the row content in the template column is not of the same height, then some extra space appears between the rows.

How to make the actual space between the rows to be the same? I have been looking in inspector to find the appropriate selector for that extra space, but I couldn't find any.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'name2',
        type: 'string'
    }],


    data: [
        {
            name1: 'John',
            name2: 'Smith',
        },
        {
            name1: '',
            name2: '',
        },
        {
            name1: 'Homer',
            name2: 'Simson',
        },        
    ],
});


Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 700,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            cls: 'grid',
            //rowLines: false,
            height: 700,
            store: store,
            columns: [
                {
                        text: '',
                        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                        cell: {
                            encodeHtml: false
                        },              
                        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                            '<div class="grid-box">',
                            '<div class="name">{name1}</div>',
                            '<div class="name">{name2}</div>',
                            '</div>',
                        ),
                        flex: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

CSS

```
.grid .x-show-selection > .x-listitem.x-selected {
    background-color: pink;
}

.grid .x-show-selection > .x-listitem.x-selected {
    background-color: pink;
}

.grid .x-listitem {
    background-color: #a9f1ad;
}

.grid-box {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #cbd2d6;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid .x-gridcell-body-el {
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}

.name {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:22px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set min-height in your CSS:

```
.name {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    min-height: 22px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one more question please since we are at that case. If name1 or name2 is the very long string, how to break the line?

Comment: I think it is word-wrap and word-break CSS properties: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-word-break-break-all-versus-word-wrap-break-word-in-css/

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all of that, and nothing works,